# Where can I find the legend?

Tags: qgis, legend, area

I have downloaded the following two tiff files from [here](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/QQHCIK):

- pnv_biome.type_biome00k_c_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1
- pnv_biome.type_biome00k_sse_1km_s0..0cm_2000..2017_v0.1

Using `r.report` in QGIS 3.6 I have calculated area. Results are the following:

[image]

[image]

I could not find the legend. Hence, I do not know which land cover types correspond to numbers. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Same place you got the data. Download the [filename].tif.csv associated with [filename].tif

E.g. https://dataverse.harvard.edu/file.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/QQHCIK/JUBLYL&version=4.0

```
"","Number","New.global.consolidated.biome.scheme","Original_biome_classification","Mega_biome_classification","R","G","B","Opacity","Group"
"1",1,"tropical evergreen broadleaf forest","tropical evergreen broadleaf forest","tropical forest",28,85,16,255,"tropical.evergreen.broadleaf.forest"
"2",2,"tropical semi-evergreen broadleaf forest","tropical semi-evergreen broadleaf forest","tropical forest",101,146,8,255,"tropical.semi.evergreen.broadleaf.forest"
etc...
```

[image]